# isEnabled() function not working in Protractor

Tags: protractor

I want to select a date in calendar picker using protractor. Below is the snippet of code, that I have written in my script:

```
if (dat <= 24) {
    var us_dat = element(by.xpath("(//a[text()='" + dat + "'])[1]"));
} else {
    var us_dat = element(by.xpath("(//a[text()='" + dat + "'])[1]"));
    if (us_dat.isEnabled() == false) {
        var us_dat = element(by.xpath("(//a[text()='" + dat + "'])[2]"));
    }
}

us_dat.click();
browser.sleep(1000);
```

where `dat` is a variable, where I have stored the date that needs to be selected in the calendar picker.

During debugging, I found that, when the date is greater than 24, the code is checking the "if" block present under the "else" block. However, it returns a value of undefined and hence it is skipping the action written inside the "if" block. May I know why it is returning a value of "undefined", instead of true or false please?

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Answer (score 0):

Because all Protractor's API is Async and return promise. So `isEnabled()` is not return `Boolean` value directly, you can't directly compare it with a boolean value. You should do the comparing in `then()` or use `await`.

Another thing, you no need to put xpath into `()`, like `(//a[text()='click me'])`.

```
var us_dat = element(by.xpath("//a[text()='" + dat + "'][1]"));

us_dat.isEnabled().then(function(enabled){
   if (dat > 24 && enabled=== false) {
       return element(by.xpath("//a[text()='" + dat + "'][2]"));
   } else {
       return us_dat;
   }     
})
.then(function(ele){
   ele.click();
   browser.sleep(1000);
});
```

Comment: I have tried with the given code and still it is not working. While debugging, i can see that, after execution of then function, if condition under the then function is not executed rather it jumps out of the loop and trying to click the element (i.e us_dat.click(); - this line gets executed). So, is that something else needs to be added in the code?

Comment: what's value of `enabled` when you debug? it's `true` or `false`

Comment: Hi Yong,                                                                                        
Neither it is true or false. Rather, it is showing an error stating that **"ReferenceError: enabled is not defined"**. Please help

Comment: it's no possible to give such error,  double check to see anything missed in your local code.  Did you copy my code or type your code follow me.

Comment: Hi Yong, Initially, i have just copied it. But, now i rewrite the code on my own, and still can see the value of enabled as "ReferenceError: enabled is not defined".

Comment: Current Piece of code looks like as below

 if (dat <= 24) {
                        var us_dat = element(by.xpath("//a[text()='" + dat + "'][1]"));
                        //dat.count

                    }
                    else {
                        var us_dat = element(by.xpath("//a[text()='" + dat + "'][1]"));
                        us_dat.isEnabled().then(function(enabled){
                            if(!enabled) {
                                us_dat = element(by.xpath("//a[text()='" + dat + "'][2]"));
                            }
                        });

Comment: I have no idea now.  Try change the `enabled` to any valid variable name like `aa`,  then run script again to see it will say 'ReferenceError: aa is not defined' . Another thing,  did you add 'use strict' at head of script file?

Comment: I have not added "use strict" at the head of script file. It is not working, even when i replaced "enabled" with "aa" or any other variable name. When i clicked evaluate expression in webstorm during debugging, it always showing *"Reference Error"*.

Just to note, there are other text fields, which has been automated earlier, before automating the calendar picker in the application. Even for those fields, during debugging, the same error is retrieved from promises, however, the scripts works fine during the actual run without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
try to use this method will work

isEnable: function (element) {
        return element.isEnabled();
    },
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.